# sql server - Combine tables into one table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, each one has 'Date','Time' and 'ID' Columns and about 100 extra columns that's represents counters, Also I have a master table that contains 'Date','Time' and 'ID' columns plus it has all the counters that exited in the other 2 tables.

I need a way to update the master tables from the 4 tables, Like as below:

```
Table 1

Date,Time,ID,Counter_A,Counter_B

01012014,00:00:00,1,10,20

01012014,00:00:00,2,7,8

21012014,00:00:00,1,3,1


Table 2

Date,Time,ID,Counter_C,Counter_D

01012014,00:00:00,1,30,40

01012014,00:00:00,2,5,9

21012014,00:00:00,1,4,2`

Master Table

Date,Time,ID,Counter_A,Counter_B,Counter_C,Counter_D
01012014,00:00:00,1,10,20,30,40

01012014,00:00:00,2,7,8,5,9

21012014,00:00:00,1,3,1,4,2
```

I tried Dynamic Sql with INSERT but it's takes too long especially I have about 100,000 row in each of table 1 and table 2 and some times it's back with timeout expiry error.

By the way I get daily updates for (tables 1 and table 2) as CSV files, is there any way to update the Master table with out taking too much time.

More detail:

Hi, thank you for your answer,

Let me explain more: what I'm trying to do is storing statistics for a system, the statistics is counters for operations and operations success and fail rates and etc...

I get hourly statistics every day, I get them in 4 CSV files, I processed the gathering of these data into tables, so I get 4  new tables every day.

so I get for each ID 24 value for each counters, I have about 300 counters from all files.

The master table has all the 300 columns, some times when I export the CSV files from the system, I neglect some counters or add extra counters (columns).

the data in the system is in this way:
Date Time ID ColA ColB .......... ColC ColD

but the export from system has limitations in the number of exported columns (counters) per file, so I have to separate the columns into 4 files, so the date, time and ID is the same only the counters are differs from file to file.

My approach is to combine the counters all together in one table like they was in the system.

Comment: Is it `insert` or `update`?

Comment: Use UNION to combine them

Comment: Dear LIUFA, It's INSERT, because the Master table had to store the old values.

Comment: Dear Daniel E. , I'm using Dynamic sql because table 1 and table 2 may not contain all columns in the Master table, I'm doing this to prevent error if the column is not exist in table 1 or table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `UNION ALL` statement, it allows you to combine data from multiple tables into single dataset.
 If you have columns that are missing (Counter_C,Counter_D in table1) you substitute them with `NULL` or default values (0, '',...).
 If you want only unique values (if same value from two tables should not be inserted) then instead of using `UNION ALL` you should use `UNION`.

```
INSERT INTO MasterTable (Date,Time,ID,Counter_A,Counter_B,Counter_C,Counter_D) 
SELECT Date,Time,ID,Counter_A,Counter_B,NULL,NULL
FROM Table1
UNION ALL 
SELECT Date,Time,ID,NULL,NULL,Counter_C,Counter_D
FROM Table2
UNION ALL
...
```

If you want to UPDATE values you will have to list the columns and wrap unionised SELECT statement.

```
UPDATE M SET Date = X.Date, Time = X.Time, ID = X.ID, Counter_A = X.Counter_A, Counter_B = X.Counter_B, Counter_C = X.Counter_C, Counter_D = X.Counter_D) 
FROM MasterTable M, (    
SELECT Date,Time,ID,Counter_A,Counter_B,NULL,NULL
    FROM Table1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Date,Time,ID,NULL,NULL,Counter_C,Counter_D
    FROM Table2
    UNION ALL
    ...) AS X
WHERE M.ID = X.ID
```

Comment: that is how I would do it

Answer (score 0):

i'm sorry but i didnt understand your question... from my point of view, "Master Table" looks like a join from T1 and T2... if this is correct, you can create a view, replacing "Master Table" and follow [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180800.aspx) on how to update it